# Globally autoloading class

Tags: php

Is there a way to globally load a class for all PHP scripts in a specific installation? Or, in other words, extend the PHP interpreter to provide a class globally? My intention is to build a centralized logging facility for all PHP web applications on a server, but I don't want to repeat calling `require()`, `use` and `Autoloader` statements in every script.

It would be even better to have a global logging object available in every script, but that would require to have some kind of thread-safe object and/or locking.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) the short answer is yes: you can make a class available globally for all scripts running on a single machine by writing a PHP extension. Provided your code is running on the binary with your extension compiled and enabled into it, the class is available. 2) Is it really that much effort to write `use` once or twice in a file? I mean: seriously, register a decent autoloader, and follow the PHP-FIG standards. That'll save you the hastle of writing `require`, at least

Comment: PS: Voted to close as too broad, unclear what you're asking and not offering a clear description of the problem, nor do you provide a code example to replicate or at least better understand the problems you're trying to solve.

Comment: How is it unclear, when you just answered the question? How would I provide a code example, when I am asking a general, albeit quite specific question?

Comment: I don't know if I really did. I don't know what you actually mean when you say a class should be available _globally_. I'm not sure what you mean when you say you have to repeat `require` calls. Once a class is `require`'d, it's defined. You don't have to require the same file over and over (you'll get errors if you do). PHP is stateless, remember: registering a class globally implies that it'll be loaded and destroyed for each individual request (during `PHP_MINIT` and `PHP_MSHUTDOWN` respectively). Tell us what your problem is, because 9/10, there's an alternative to what you want to do now

Comment: I guess when you read the sentence "my intention is to build a centralized logging facility for all PHP web applications on a server" the meaning of "globally" is pretty clear. Good point about loading the class with each request. Doesn't the PHP interpreter continue to run when I am using mod_php with Apache? What about "extension globals"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I understand that the best way to achieve this is to write a PHP extension that implements the class so it's available in all scripts on a server. Additonally I found an extension called "php-logger-extension" that does exactly that:

"By using the php_logger the application just need to load the extension once, this is done when the web server is initialized, also the application does not need to parse any php classes in order to be able to log."

https://code.google.com/p/php-logger-extension/